# WordPress: Does free version of wpDataTables plugin work for Report builder add-on?

Tags: wordpress, reportbuilder

Does free version of wpDataTables plugin work for Report builder add-on or do I have to buy premium version ?
I wanted to use the doc generation functionality of report builder wherein the data from excel sheets is mapped on a doc template and we could download a doc version of it.

Please help.

Comment: You can get help from [" https://wpdatatables.com/pricing/  "], Or you can contact customer support of the company. Please read  this article before posting any question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, the free version does not provide this functionality, but you can try this out on your own and see how it goes to confirm, OR you can reach their team via their official website, and they'll explain everything you need.